# How to properly a Pytorch geometric GNN model for my custom toy dataset?

Tags: pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I created my own custom toy dataset of graphs in order to learn graph neural networks in Pytorch-geopmetric (PyG).
The data looks like the following:

```
Data(x=[20, 1], edge_index=[2, 20], y=[1])
```

I also created a dataloader as follows:

from torch_geometric.loader import DataLoader

```
train_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset[0:8000], batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(dataset[8000:10000], batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

Therefore, a batch will look like:

```
DataBatch(x=[640, 1], edge_index=[2, 640], y=[32], batch=[640], ptr=[33])
```

My attempt to make a Graph-CNN:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(dataset[0].num_node_features, 16)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(16, 16)
        self.out = nn.Linear(16, 1)

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index = data.x, data.edge_index

        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = F.dropout(x, training=self.training)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        
        out = self.out(x)

        return out

model = GCN()
```

When I do something like:

```
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
target = batch.y.to(torch.float32)  
loss = criterion(out, target)
loss
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (640) to match target batch_size (32).
```

Full code is in my github repo here:
https://github.com/amine179/myGNN-learning/blob/main/My%20first%20GCNN.ipynb

Comment: You need to apply one of the [pooling layers](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/nn.html#pooling-layers). For example, add this statement into GCN forward function.
'x = global_add_pool(x, batch)'